# How is localized data binding set up with JSON files and XML views?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have an XMLView home page containing some tiles. These tiles are populated from a JSON file. The tiles have a 'title' attribute which requires i18n data binding.

Part of the XML view:

```
<TileContainer id="container" tiles="{/TileCollection}">
  <StandardTile
   icon="{icon}"
   title="{title}"
   press="onPress" />
</TileContainer>
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "TileCollection" : [
      {
          "icon"   : "sap-icon://document-text",
          "title"  : "{i18n>foo}"
      }, 
      ... etc
```

The old way I accomplished data binding was directly in the view with `title="{i18n>foo}"`. Of course now I have essentially two layers of data binding, one in the JSON for the i18n, and one in the view to get the JSON (which gets the i18n).

This is also my Component.js where I set up the i18n model.

```
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("MYAPP.Component", {
  metadata: {
    rootView : "MYAPP.view.Home", //points to the default view

    config: {
      resourceBundle: "i18n/messageBundle.properties"
    },
    ... etc


  init: function(){
    sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
    var mConfig = this.getMetadata().getConfig();

    var oRouter = this.getRouter();
    this.RouteHandler = new sap.m.routing.RouteMatchedHandler(oRouter);
    oRouter.register("router");
    oRouter.initialize();

    var sRootPath = jQuery.sap.getModulePath("MYAPP");
    var i18nModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({
        bundleUrl : [sRootPath, mConfig.resourceBundle].join("/")
    });
    this.setModel(i18nModel, "i18n");
}
```

This question arose from discussion about another question, so there may be more info there for anyone interested. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28827702/retrieving-the-id-from-a-control-to-use-in-navigation)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The approach I usually take is using a formatter function, which sole purpose is to get the correct localized value for a certain key (which is maintained in the resource model, and driven by the data model)

For instance, the Tile UI would look like this:

```
<TileContainer id="container" tiles="{/tiles}">
    <StandardTile
      icon="{icon}"
      type="{type}"
      title="{ path : 'title', formatter : '.getI18nValue' }"
      info="{ path : 'info', formatter : '.getI18nValue' }"
      infoState="{infoState}" 
      press="handlePress"/>
</TileContainer>
```

*(Notice the formatter function `getI18nValue` for properties `title` and `info`; these are the properties to be translated. The other properties come as-is from the bound JSONModel)*

The model could look like this:

```
tiles : [
    {
        icon      : "sap-icon://inbox",
        number    : "12",
        title     : "inbox",   // i18n property 'inbox'
        info      : "overdue", // i18n property 'overdue'
        infoState : "Error"
    },
    {
        icon      : "sap-icon://calendar",
        number    : "3",
        title     : "calendar", // i18n property 'calendar'
        info      : "planned",  // i18n property 'planned'
        infoState : "Success"
    }
]
```

where the `title` and `info` property values of the JSONModel (for instance, 'inbox' and 'overdue') correspond with a key in your resourcebundle files (and thus your ResourceModel)

The formatter function in the controller (or better, in a standalone JS file, for re-use in multiple views) is then pretty simple:

```
getI18nValue : function(sKey) {
    return this.getView().getModel("i18n").getProperty(sKey);
}
```

It does nothing more than supplying the value from the model (for instance, 'inbox') and returning the localized value for this key from the resource model